# ionic1 wait http response of next view before load it

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm using ionic to create an application who retrieve data from api through http request when I change view I see the view before the data of the controller totally loaded :

[image]

How can I load data of the next controller to only see the final result :

[image]

here the button who start the change of view :

```
<ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" ng-repeat="inscription in inscriptions" ng-click="loadActiProfil({{inscription}})" href="#/app/activite">
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You shouldn't wait for your HTTP response to start the navigation transition, on a UX perspective. ionic provides a service called [$ionicLoading](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) which allows displaying and hiding a spinner (with a black&transparent backdrop). You may use it to make your user understand that he/she's supposed to wait.* But enough with my personal opinion.

Regarding your need:

- Do not use `href` to change the current state, you'd rather use `ui-sref`, as it's supposed to be done using angular-ui router (which is, of course, ionic's router too). NB: `ui-sref` expects a **state name** and not an URI (for instance, `"app.home"`).
- Use your method `loadActiProfil` to programmatically switch from the previous state to the new one only once your data is available, thanks to the service `$state` and its method `go` (ie: `$state.go('app.home')` will take you to the state app.home)

TL;DR: if you need to switch the current state programmatically, then use `$state.go(stateName)`, not `ui-sref` (nor `href`).

Comment: I used $state.go() to go to the next view and $ionicLoading but i continue to see the loading behind the loading screen and it's really ugly. Is there a way to show loading screen, wait http response of the next controller, show the the next view and finally hide laoding screen?

Comment: The process is to: 1 - Show the $ionicLoading, 2 - Send your http request, 3 - In the http response CALLBACK: - 3.1 hide $ionicLoading - 3.2 $state.go to your state. You have to show the ionic loading and send your http request in the "main flow", then do the rest in the callback given to $http (if that's what you're using to perform http requests).

Comment: i'm sorry i don't see how i can do this if i do the request in the first controller scope the data ($scope.data=data) then state.go(secondcontroller) the data are not visible in the second view.

Comment: For sure they're not, the data will necessarily be obtained by the first controller. But that's a different issue ! Using AngularJS, you can create a service/factory which will store your data for both controllers.

Comment: An other way (cleaner) to achieve your transition would be to display a ion-spinner on your second view unless "data" is initialized. Then, once it is, and only at this time, display your current template, filled with the data sent by your API.

Comment: Glad to know :)! By the way, if you just started learning ionic1, I'd recommend switching (if possible) to ionic 2. Indeed, the support for ionic 1 is almost dropped now... (Yet you can create nice apps with Ionic 1, for sure. I did :).)